# trying to get msysgit installed via chocolatey with chef but it's hanging

Tags: installation, msysgit, chef, chocolatey

I'm building a Go-Agent that's deployable via chef to AWS (to give you some context)
Part of that is installing Msysgit and as I look it's been 1 hour and 3 mins since it's started trying to install it. 
I
fF however you go onto the box and type `cinst msysgit` it installs with no problems.

Any ideas on what's causing it to hang?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies! I meant to post this but kinda forgot about this.

It was fixed by installing the version below it, suddenly the problem went away;
specifically we moved from version '1.9.5.20150114' to '1.9.5' and it installed.

I'm still not sure what cause it but that was the fix.

Answer (score 1):

It could be several reasons, including the particular installer wanting to be interactive. If this happens only with particular packages, I would move towards that being the issue. But I've heard of other things that seem to get no priority when run as a background job.